# Dataframe error when using GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: pyspark, model, databricks

I am getting this error when I run my code: TypeError: Cannot recognize a pipeline stage of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>, specicifically when I fit the pipeline to my data. I think I may be loading my csv incorrectly but am not sure, here is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import numpy as np
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline,PipelineModel
from pyspark.ml.classification import GBTClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer,OneHotEncoderEstimator

from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("FileStore/tables/data.csv")


str_indxr = StringIndexer(inputCol="PointDiff", outputCol="label")
str_indxr = str_indxr.fit(df).transform(df)

str_indxr.columns
vec_assmblr = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['label','col1', 'col2', 'col3'], outputCol='features_norm')
splits =df.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])
df_train = splits[0]
df_test = splits[1]
gbt = GBTClassifier(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features_norm", maxIter=10)
pip_line = Pipeline(stages=[str_indxr,vec_assmblr,gbt])
pip_line_fit = pip_line.fit(df_train)

df_tran = pip_line_fit.transform(df_test)
```

Comment: did you get a chance to try out the answer? did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

In this line of your code `str_indxr = str_indxr.fit(df).transform(df)` already you convert your string indexer stage into a dataframe. so when you use it in this line `pip_line = Pipeline(stages=[str_indxr,vec_assmblr,gbt])` str_indxr is now a dataframe and not a string indexer stage.

So either skip the step or assign the output of `str_indxr = str_indxr.fit(df).transform(df)` to a different name.

another hint - you are using your target label also in your VectorAssembler input. this is not correct.

Comment: what should the input be in my VectorAssembler? When I skip the step you advised is get there error: 'Data type string of column col1 is not supported.\nData type..' and so on with the rest of my columns

Comment: Models do not understand strings. So you either convert them to integer using string indexer or to array using OneHotCodeEstimator

Answer (score 0):

I think your setup should be like this.

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import GBTClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorIndexer
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

# Load and parse the data file, converting it to a DataFrame.
data = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

# Index labels, adding metadata to the label column.
# Fit on whole dataset to include all labels in index.
labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="label", outputCol="indexedLabel").fit(data)
# Automatically identify categorical features, and index them.
# Set maxCategories so features with > 4 distinct values are treated as continuous.
featureIndexer =\
    VectorIndexer(inputCol="features", outputCol="indexedFeatures", maxCategories=4).fit(data)

# Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

# Train a GBT model.
gbt = GBTClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol="indexedFeatures", maxIter=10)

# Chain indexers and GBT in a Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[labelIndexer, featureIndexer, gbt])

# Train model.  This also runs the indexers.
model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)

# Make predictions.
predictions = model.transform(testData)

# Select example rows to display.
predictions.select("prediction", "indexedLabel", "features").show(5)

# Select (prediction, true label) and compute test error
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
    labelCol="indexedLabel", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy")
accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Test Error = %g" % (1.0 - accuracy))

gbtModel = model.stages[2]
print(gbtModel)  # summary only
```

Documentation Here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#gradient-boosted-tree-classifier